# Anonymous class

Tags: ruby

Here is an example:

```
class A
  class << self
    p superclass
  end
end

a = A.new

class << a
  p superclass
end
```

This code print:

```
#<Class:Object>
A
```

Why instead of

```
Class 
A
```

print line

```
#<Class:Object>
A
```

?

For an anonymous class

```
  class << self
    p superclass
  end
```

superclass is Class

Comment: Please note that a metaclass, which can contain singleton methods, is not quite the same as an anonymous class, which is defined using `Class.new do # ..`

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure if I understand the question correctly. Please rephrase it or provide more details in case I misunderstood it.

A call to `superclass` returns an object, which in this case is `Class`. In Ruby everything is an object. To my knowledge this is correct behaviour.

If you want to see the name of the class only, call `p superclass.name`.

**Edit** A call to `superclass` can return `nil`. When you do: `class << a`, you are extending `a` with new methods (take a look at [this reading about classes, objects and modules](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/classes.html)). Since `a` is an `Object` (an instance of class `A`), it has no superclass - `Object` is the top of hierarchy tree. Class `A` has a superclass (class named `Class`), but not the instance of `A` it.

Comment: <code>p superclass.name</code> in class A print nil. Code <code>class << a
  p superclass.name
end</code> print "A". Why nil?